# Is it good practice to use unique_ptr as an alternative to my own move constructors?

Tags: c++

I'm making a card game using C++. It's similar to solitaire, i.e. there are different stacks and piles and the cards are moved from one to another.

I'm using `std::vector` for the various piles, but instead of `std::vector<Card>`, I'm using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Card>>`. My rationale for doing this is that:

1. It ensures that the ownership responsibility is with the `vector` that it is currently in.
2. It makes sure that I never accidentally have more than 1 copy of the same card when transferring between stacks and piles, i.e. forces me to transfer using `std::move`.
3. I don't have to implement my own copy and move constructors for `Card`.

Is this a reasonable way to use `unique_ptr`?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, there are different types of `Card`s which are derived from a base class. I'm a beginner and didn't want to muck around with different copy and move constructors at all levels.

Comment: @LixinWei why do you mention `shared_ptr`, the question is about `unique_ptr` and unique ownership.

Comment: The downside of this (and it’s a serious downside in my book) is that you’re giving up value semantics in your interface. C++ likes value semantics. It makes code simpler and cleaner. Of your three points, (1) isn’t relevant with value semantics. (3) is trivial to achieve by following the rule of zero, and (2) can be accomplished differently.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'd say that is *the* feature here: these playing cards have entity semantics, not value semantics.

Comment: @Quentin What’s “entity semantics”? It’s not a thing in C++, and in fact the cards in OP’s code have *pointer semantics*. This is more an anti-feature than a feature.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "pointer semantics" might be a better C++-ese word for that, yes. This is useful because, as OP describes, the cards are modeled one-to-one with unique (and supposedly immutable) objects that are only passed around. On the other hand, value semantics would dissociate a card (the object) from its face (the value), allowing several cards to have the same face or even cards with no face at all, which does not seem useful here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph • Evans Classification is an object-oriented way to categorize objects as **entity** object, **value** objects, or **service** objects.  It is just as applicable to OO in C++ as it is to any other language doing OO.  When applied to C++, it helps to make classes less muddled than when classes blend entity or value or service semantics together.  A `Card` has **value** semantics, and is not *polymorphic*, and does not have mutating *state-over-time*.  So `std::vector<std::unique<Card>>` seems like a suspect choice.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks to Eljay’s comment I now know what you’re talking about. Still, I maintain that pointer semantics are rarely if ever the right choice for APIs in C++. The Evans classification is a logical layer *on top of* C++’s physical type semantics. That is, it’s entirely possible (if appropriate, which I’m still not convinced here!) to have a value type that models an entity. It does require some work under the hood but it makes usage much easier.

Comment: @KonradRudolph apologies for the half-remember OOP course, that didn't help at all did it :p -- Basically, the idea is to design the code such that accidental card duplication cannot happen. In C++, this is modeled with move-only types, by having the move-constructor leave the original in an "empty" state. Since that is exactly the functionality provided by an `std::unique_ptr` to a plain `Card` class, it does sound like a fair first shot to me. Also note that implementing the logic in `Card` itself *would* require a custom move-constructor if it uses a primitive type to store its face value.

Comment: @Quentin could you please elaborate on the last sentence? Why would I need a custom move constructor if I use a primitive member to store value? Wouldn't default move constructor suffice?

Comment: @PlastyGrove because move-constructing a primitive type performs a copy and does not clear the original.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. It ensures that the ownership responsibility is with the vector that it is currently in.

This makes little sense to me. Vector owns all its elements, so unique pointer adds nothing of value in this regard.

> 2. It makes sure that I never accidentally have more than 1 copy of the same card when transferring between stacks and piles, i.e. forces me to transfer using std::move.

If preventing copying is useful, then another alternative would be to make `Card` non-copyable - or keep `Card` copyable and create a non-copyable wrapper. In a way, `std::unique_ptr<Card>` could be seen as such wrapper, but it is more than just a wrapper and unnecessarily inefficient and complicated for that use case. A simple example:

```
struct UniqueCard : Card {
    using Card::Card;

    UniqueCard(UniqueCard&&) = default;
    UniqueCard& operator=(UniqueCard&&) = default;

    UniqueCard(const UniqueCard&) = delete;
    UniqueCard& operator=(const UniqueCard&) = delete;
};
```

Note that this design implies that cards must have some "empty" state, that they will be left in after move. This corresponds to having a null pointer in the stack that would be the case when moving from a unique pointer.

I'm not convinced that this is necessarily better than just allowing copying and leaving the responsibility to the user of the class to follow the rules of the game.

> Is this a reasonable way to use unique_ptr?

Preventing copying alone is not a reasonable reason to use a unique pointer.

A different design that I would recommend trying out: Instead of storing the cards in vectors, represent the card stacks with linked lists. To move from stack to another, extract the node and splice into another list. This way the cards can be immutable, don't need to represent "empty" card, and you don't end up with duplicates.

---

> I forgot to mention that there are different types of Cards which are derived from a base class

You cannot store derived class instances in a vector that contains base class objects. Storing derived instances **is** a use case where `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Card>>` is reasonable, because a pointer can point to the base class sub object of the derived instances.

Note that dynamic polymorphism is not necessarily the best solution for a card game.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that there are different types of `Card`s which are derived from a base class. I am a beginner and didn't want to muck around with move and copy constructors for all the various classes. Do you think it's easy enough to make all of them non-copyable?

Comment: `A better alternative would be to make Card non-copyable ` it isn't copyable and stored in a vector that it has to be moveable?

Comment: @t.niese Yes, if a class is not copyable, then it must be movable in order to store it in a vector.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! One question, is it sufficient to just make the base class non-copyable? Or do I have to make all the derived classes also non-copyable?

Comment: @PlastyGrove Yes, if the base is non-copyable, then the children will be as well implicitly.

Comment: I tried this, but I ran into another issue. I have pointers to the `Card` elements in various places. In `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Card>>`, the pointer to `Card` is always consistent irrespective of which vector now holds the `unique_ptr`. This is no longer the case if I use a `std::vector<Card>`.

Comment: @PlastyGrove That's right. Did you try out the linked list suggestion?

Comment: @eerorika - Ah I missed that, let me give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: @eerorika - I do appreciate your help and I learnt a lot from your answer, but it feels like a lot of extra work to just avoid using `unique_ptr`, i.e. rolling out my own linked list implementation. I guess I could also continue with `vector` by rolling out my own barebones `CardHolder` which has a `Card` member variable, but again seems unnecessary when a `unique_ptr` does the job for me. Should I avoid it because I could possibly shoot myself in the foot with `unique_ptr` or is it because it is semantically incorrect?

Comment: @PlastyGrove There isn't a need to roll out your own. There is a linked list in the standard library. It's called `std::list`.

Comment: @eerorika - Ah my bad, you're right, `splice` in `std::list` works as expected when moving between lists, let me give that a try!